# Microsoft FAST observing inner properties of an array

Tags: javascript, observable

I am using Microsoft FAST framework (fast.design) and am working inside a class which extends FASTElement. I have an array with the following structure myArray: {itemOne: string, itemTwo: {keyOne: string, keyTwo: boolean}[]}[] which I am using with a two repeat directives to render my dom. The first repeat is used to loop through the outer array (myArray) and the second nested repeat directive to loop through the inner array in itemTwo. My issue is I need to change the items within my array and have the dom rerender.

In the documentation it says to use splice when editing arrays, however this does not rerender as my array is an array of objects. I have also tried calling Observable.notify(myArray, index) however this also did not work. In the documentation it says I need to individually observe the objects and nested arrays but I was not able to figure out how to do this.

The following is my code.

```js
import { FASTElement, customElement, observable, html, repeat, Observable, when } from '@microsoft/fast-element';

@customElement('my-element')
export class MyElement extends FASTElement {
    @observable myArray: {itemOne: string, itemTwo: {keyOne: string, keyTwo: boolean}[]}[];

    changeItem(index: number) {
    // Change item at index
    // I need to be able to change the nested array in itemTwo - I do not need to change the individual values of the objects, just add or remove objects from the array in ItemTwo
    //Observable.notify(this.myArray, index); // notify the system that the item has changed
  }

}
```

Template:

```html
<div>
  ${repeat(x => x.myArray, html`
    <p>${x => x.itemOne}</p>
    <ul>
      ${repeat(x => x.itemTwo, html`
        ${when(x => x.keyTwo, html`
          <li>${x => x.keyOne}: ${x => x.keyTwo}</li>
        `)}
      `)}
    </ul>
  `)}
</div>
```

Note: Although I did not include the template and styles as part of my custom element in the code above, my template is connected properly.

Comment: Hi, please format your code; as written, you have little chance of getting answers. Read : [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)